# AWS subdomain delegation

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I need to connect an App i have on AWS (using elasticBS and loadBalancer) to subdomain `sub.example.com` but it seems to fail.

**Things i've done so far include:**

**1.** Route 53 - I created a hosted zone (public) for `sub.example.com` and than added an `A record` with alias to point to the load balancer.

**2.** Wrote down the Four Name Server listed on the previous step.

**3.** Delegation - I've got back to the registrar zone file and added four `NS IN records` with name `sub.example.com` and the name servers.

**4.** Waited for tooo long (>2 days) and nothing happend.

Maybe someone can shed some light on this please, thanks.

Comment: Why not just create the CNAME record at your primary DNS service that points to the load balancer's DNS name? Why use Route53 for this?

Comment: Thank you. didn't know that option exist. now it works but for http only. i need to figure out how to do this for https too.

Comment: If the DNS works for HTTP then you are done making DNS changes. For HTTPS to work you need to configure an SSL certificate on your load balancer.

Comment: It's working now. thank you thank you.